# A question from the Romanian Olympiad

Tags: abstract-algebra, contest-math

Let $(A,+,*)$ be a ring such that $1+\dots+1(2021$ of $1)=0$. Let $a,b\in A$ such that $ab=ba$, for which exists $m,n\in N$,odd numbers, such that $a^m=b^n=1$.Let the statements:

E1: $1+1$ is invertible

E2: $a+b$ is invertible

Than: (choose the corect answer)

A.The both statements are false.

B.Just E1 is true.

C.Just E2 is true.

D.The both statements are true.

E.The assumptions of the problem are both insufficient to determine
exactly the ruth value of the sentences.

I had to solve that problem in the District Mathematics Olympiad from my country on 20 March 2021 and I did not know how. The only idea that I have is that E2 is true and maybe I could prove that using that ab=ba. And I do not know how to use the fact that 1+1+...+1(2021 of 1)=0

Comment: Why don't you think $E1$ is true?

Comment: Well it could be.But how can I use the fact that 1+1..+1(2021 of 1)=0 ? @HereToRelax

Comment: What would you get if you add $1+1+1\dots+1$ exactly $2022$ times? Is this number a multiple of $1+1$ ?

Comment: But if statement E2 is not decidable, then - no matter what the status of statement E1 is - the answer would have to be option E, right?

Comment: What kind of $a,b$ pairs did you find when testing in the ring $\Bbb{Z}_{2021}$? If you have examples of both kinds: $a+b$ invertible and $a+b$ not invertible, then you can conclude that E2 is undecided. Otherwise, you need to think of something else. $2021=43\cdot47$, but I don't know whether that helps. It does constrain the possibilities for $m,n$ in that ring, but I haven't thought it through.

Comment: Now I know how to solve it.Thank you for the explanations.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I was thinking of `a=1`, `b=-1` for contradicting E2, but that does not work for odd `n`. So I guess E2 also holds ...

Answer (score 2):

hint for E1 was already given in the comments.

hint for E2: `a+b` divides `a^k+b^k` for odd `k`.